# Увеличение высоты блока

Tags: javascript

Нужно увеличить высоту **#block** в два раза от его текущего размера.
Набросал скрипт, но я не давно начал изучать js, вследствие чего я не правильно написал скрипт.

Пожалуйста, помогите понять, что я сделал не так?

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');   

function heigh(){
let b = a.offsetHeight * 2;
a.style.height = a.style.height * b + 'px';
}

heigh();
```

```css
#block{
background: pink;
text-align:center; 
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">
Как дела?
</div>
```

Comment: a.style.height = a.offsetHeight * 2 + 'px';

Comment: Ух, спасибо большое!